# How to change a selectors function after a click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create some jquery, it will allow a user to click on a div to make a http request. The main purpose, over show/hide, is to cut down on http requests as the content is only loaded when the user requests it.

My function is below and appears to work corerctly. But I now need to "loop" the function, or create another instance.

**The purpose of this is to allow the user to click the same div and hide the content.**

Any ideas or suggestions of better ways to do this would be greatly welcomed!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.windguru').click(function () {
        $('.loader').show(400, null, function () {
            alert('loader has been shown')
            $('.windguru-content').load("windguru1.html", function () {
                alert('iframe content loaded, will now close the loader')
                $('.loader').hide(500);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5CJ74/

Comment: if (target.text != "") {target.hide()} else { target.loader.load() }

Comment: Doesn't just creating an event to hide if the user is on the page help. Like if (click) && (.windguru-content) on page, then hide().

Comment: I would assume you want to let the user click on the div again though and reshow the information without reloading the information?

Comment: no sorry shadow as the page is an iframe i plan to create a cached version locally. Then serve with AJAX to keep the number of http requests at page load down.

Yes Mark that sounds lovely, would you mind trying to help?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to loop is to toggle a dummy class on the DOM element. In your case you want to make the show-hide actions to loop on click on $('.windguru'), then just
`$('.windguru').addClass('loaded')` when you get ajax response and 
do `$('.windguru').removeClass('loaded')` when, on click, `$('.windguru').hasClass('loaded')`.
So its like this

1. Check if `$('.windguru').hasClass('loaded')`
2. if no then, `$('.windguru').addClass('loaded')` and do rest of the ajax loading
3. if yes then, `$('.windguru').removeClass('loaded')` and hide the content.

You can improve this further by,

- caching jQuery objects instead of passing the selector every time
- Using the ajax request only when the data is requested for the first time.

Comment: i dont know if I can properly follow this Shoaib.
I've updated the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5CJ74/9/

Comment: ok, I've managed to figure out how the add/remove class would work. 
Would you mind explaining how to loop/check "if" class has (loaded) so clicking on the title closes?
Many Thanks,

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CeKKx/1/